# Error: Getting AppCompatActivity is not compatible with android:Theme.Material

Tags: android, material-design, runtimeexception, appcompatactivity

I am trying add a Navigation Drawer to my app using Material Theme. Following [this tutorial here to start](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html).

The output should look like [this GIF](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/--Jem6sRRCs8/VJ5uAHTaHLI/AAAAAAAAAtE/6GM3fmnMjc4/s1600/933fee8cf6a8f48dfc1aa971bd2cc2b0.gif):

Looks like **AppCompatActivity is not compatible with android:Theme.Material**, dont understand why?

My `res/styles.xml`:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<!-- your theme inherits from the material theme -->
<style name="MaterialTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- theme customizations -->
</style>
```

My Activity Code, simply extends `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
......
```

Now, my manifest, not that I am trying to use: the `MaterialTheme`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.focusonanywhere.www.focusonanywhere/com.focusonanywhere.www.focusonanywhere.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:122)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
        at      com.focusonanywhere.www.focusonanywhere.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at        android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at            android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at          com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like AppCompatActivity is not compatible with android:Theme.Material, dont understand why?

The `appcompat-v7` action bar backport requires the use of `Theme.AppCompat` and its sub-themes (e.g., `Theme.AppCompat.Light`). That's just the nature of that library. Your choices are:

1. Not use `AppCompatActivity` and use the native action bar, or
2. Not use `Theme.Material` and instead use `Theme.AppCompat`